# Is it possible to have an HTML table hosted on a webpage that multiple users can edit at the same time?

Tags: html

Just a few details:

I have already created a basic HTML table and added javascript functions to it to add/delete new rows dynamically. I basically want it to sort of function like Google docs (multiple ppl can edit at the same time), but a SIMPLE html table.

If I host this on a server, just a single webpage made up of an HTML table that others can edit, is it possible for multiple users to edit it at the same time? And YES I will have a database in the future..

I know it is possible, but I need some pointers., been searching on the web for 2 days already!

Links to examples would be helpful.

Thanks guys, go easy on me.. I'm still a noob here.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need some real time technology that can update all clients. Something like Signal-R would be fine. There's other options out there too depending on what stack you're working on.

Here's a getting started tutorial for Signal R - [Signal R Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Comment: I like this suggestion, it's something in the direction I am aiming for. I can somehow see how I can make this work now. I appreciate it @Harko.

Comment: @igor I'm glad you found it useful. Good luck with your project!